# django-admin command not working in Mac OS

Tags: python, django

I started Django in Mac OS and after installing Django using pip, I tried to initiated a new project using the command `django-admin startproject mysite`. I get the error `-bash: django-admin: command not found`. I make quick search in Google and haven't get any solution that works.

How to start a new project using Django using django-admin ?

Comment: Did you install Django in a virtualenv? If so, have you activated the virtualenv before running the `django-admin` command?

Comment: No, I just use the command: `pip install django`

Comment: can you locate `django-admin.py` under `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/bin` folder?

Comment: There is no `python2.7` in the lib folder

Comment: Yes, I can locate now. After entering the Python console, 
`>> import django
>> django.__file__ or `
django This will provide the django installation location

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

Comment: No, doesn't work. I get the error message `-bash: django-admin.py: command not found`

Comment: “command not found: django-admin”

django-admin should be on your system path if you installed Django via python setup.py. If it’s not on your path, you can find it in site-packages/django/bin, where site-packages is a directory within your Python installation. Consider symlinking to django-admin from some place on your path, such as /usr/local/bin.

Comment: That is according to the django troubleshooting documentation for mac osx. please refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/faq/troubleshooting/ 
Please try the top in simlinking it to /usr/local/bin:)

Answer (score 8):

I solved the issue after reading a webpage about the mentioned issue.

1. In the Python shell, write the following,

   `>> import django`
   `>> django.__file__`
   `>> django  also works`

It will provide the installation location of django.

2. Change the path to the new path `/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py`,

   `sudo ln -s  the complete path of django-admin.py      /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py`

In Mac OS, The call needs to be `django-admin.py startproject mysite` than `django-admin startproject mysite`

Comment: You should mark your answer as accepted then. The currently accpeted answer doesn't seem to have solved your problem...

Answer (score 4):

try this. this should work for you with no problem.

```
pip3 install django

python3 -m django startproject PROJECTNAME
```

you can use python and pip command without mentioning 3 either.

Answer (score 2):

First install Django, lets assume you have python3.7 and want to install django 2.0.3, in this case using pip3.7 to install

```
sudo pip3.7 install django==2.0.3
```

now try to see if django-admin.py is installed using

```
ls /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/bin
```

If you see django-admin.py just link it to the /usr/local/bin using this command

```
ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/bin /usr/local/bin/
```

Then you could run this command to create new python project

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add django to your path variables and then restart the terminal.

Comment: How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm jumping in a little late, but my installations seem to all reside away from /usr/local/bin/... . What worked for me was adding an export path in bash_profile for my django installation.

This also made me realize that it was installed globally. From what I've heard, it's better to install django locally within venv as you work on different projects. That way each virtual environment can contain its own versions and dependencies for django (and whatever else you're using). Big thanks to @Arefe.

Answer (score 0):

On mac, try to uninstall it via `python -m pip uninstall Django`, then you get the actual path to `django-admin`, then you can do `chmod +x /Users/pano/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/bin/django-admin`

```html
$ python -m pip uninstall Django
Found existing installation: Django 4.0.6
Uninstalling Django-4.0.6:
  Would remove:
    /Users/pano/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/bin/django-admin
    /Users/pano/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Django-4.0.6.dist-info/*
Proceed (Y/n)? Y
  Successfully uninstalled Django-4.0.6
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was forgot to activate the virtual environment.

```
pipenv shell
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with python3 -m django startproject PROJECTNAME

Answer (score -1):

```
pip install django
```

after

```
django-admin startproject nameProject
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).