# Mac zsh: django-admin command not found

Tags: python-3.x, django-admin, zsh

I have zsh on my mac. I did simlink as you recommended in here [django-admin command not working in Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258045/django-admin-command-not-working-in-mac-os/61425936#61425936) so in my directory `/usr/local/bin` I have another folder `bin` with files `__pycache__     django-admin.py`.

However there is still the same problem and I receive `zsh: command not found` for django-admin as well as django-admin.py

Any alternative guys? I am pretty new into programming and computer science :(

Python 3.8 Django 2.1

Answer (score 0):

before going any further in your discovery of Python and Django, you should take a moment to learn about virtual environment in Python.

Virtual env are highly recommended when working with Python. Among many other advantages, they simplify the access to installed packages, or command line utilities like django-admin.

I picked a tutorial that looks ok but there are plenty of them on the web : https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Good luck in your pydventure ;)

Comment: I started new project using virtualenv interpreter (PyCharm). It works however I don't know why ;D It makes me laugh but that is just beginning so it probably is supposed to look like that. I will dig into this tutorial you posted. Thank you!